# How to enclose code snippet in a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Need some help writing this code.

I am looking to make a spreadsheet with one staff member per a sheet in one workbook. I know it is this to start off with:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sales');
ss.insertSheet(1, {template: templateSheet});
```

I am having trouble starting and ending the code.
Can someone write the code and add a "joe doe" & "jane doe" as placeholders? I will do the modifying on my end.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly:

```
function generateSheets()
{
  var staff = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe"];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales");

  for (var i = staff.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    ss.insertSheet("Sales for " + staff[i], 1, {template: templateSheet});
}
```